# Will less trees mean a higher chance for bugs to spawn on the given trees?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing New Leaf, on my Tropical Island, I have many trees that are out of the way and hard to use properly. I plan on removing them, but, when I do, will there be a higher chance for bugs to spawn on the trees that are there, or, will the chance decrease due to less trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be *exactly* what you're looking for, but at the very least it'll help.

#### There is a maximum number of spawns that can exist in your town. (There's a minimum too, but that isn't important here.)

Spawns are actual bugs and fish in your town. Bugs and fish are **both** counted towards your total spawns. In other words, there is no separate counter for bugs or fish. They are counted together towards the maximum spawn limit.

#### Scaring (or catching) bugs and fish away will allow you to find higher worth bugs and fish quicker, *however* this does not change the expensive bugs and fish's spawn percentage.

Say you have three trees on your island and four insects can be found: Common, Uncommon, Rare, Super Rare. If the common insect has a spawn percentage of 80%, the uncommon one has a spawn percentage of 50%, the rare one has a spawn percentage of 30% and the Super Rare has a spawn percentage of 15%, you'll still see more of the common one over the uncommon one, regardless of how many trees are on the island (same goes for the other types).

#### Having more trees is helpful... if you're using them well.

What I've told you so far is...

1. Insects and fish spawns count towards a spawn maximum.
2. The spawn rate for spawned creatures does not change.

So that leads to the last question: **If there are fewer trees, will there be a higher chance of insects spawning on those trees?**

Short answer, yes and no.

Long answer: If you are cutting down trees having to do with an environmental chance, like for example coconut trees, by removing some of them the others will seem to spawn more regularly. Are they? M....maybe?

If there are more common animals that can spawn on the the island (based on your tree types, the time of day, etc. etc.) those animals still have the same chance of spawning as they did when you had more trees. And of course, the fish count towards this end goal too. So if you're just asking about insects in general, I wouldn't say you have more of a chance of spawning insects on trees, per se, you would just have more real estate for insects to use. If you're scaring off the fish as they appear and getting rid of other bugs as well, then... I think yes, having few trees will work for you. If you're only scaring the tree insects away, then I can't say that'll help much.

In the end, it depends on a lot of percentages and how you deal with other spawns. But suffice it to say having 1 tropical tree that the Golden Stag can spawn on will not lead to you catching more Golden Stags, regardless of how you deal with other spawns.

See this [guide](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Fishing+And+Bug+Hunting) for more information.

Comment: I ended up setting up an evenly spaced ring of palms on the beach and then a grid of fruit trees in the middle. Then I just walk a loop around the island doing a small loop in the middle each lap. 9 times out of 10 I'm just scaring away the bugs that are there, running off roaches and catch/release butterflies to keep. This process give's me rare bugs pretty frequently and I can fill up my storage in no time at all with rare bugs.